# jquery placement of validation message

Tags: jquery, validation, message

Hi i would like to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/michelejs/Ax7Bs/ but how do I get the erros message to appear at the top of the page instead of after each element? I would also like the error messages to be hyperlinks that will set focus to the element when they are clicked

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ax7Bs/2/)

Comment: @joel - Did you get a chance to take a look at this?